# CSS center a ul list

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="design-centre-links">
<li><a href="#design-centre">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="design-centre.php?action=video-testimonials">Video Tertimonials</a></li>
<li><a href="design-centre.php?action=meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>
<li><a href="design-centre.php?action=faq">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

...and I am trying to center my list so its in the middle of the page. Here is the CSS I tried, but did not work:

```
ul.design-centre-links {
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

ul.design-centre-links {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You mean this? ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2L3qedq/1/).

Comment: you're just missing the addition of the li in the second css selector..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ben Sewards says, use

```
ul.design-centre-links li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

instead only

```
ul.design-centre-links {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

Edit:

You may use also

```
ul.design-centre-links > li {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```